# ExtJS Modern - What initialization function to implement when extending a component

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, initialization

In ExtJS 6.2 classic we usually implement `initComponent` when we extend a component.

On ExtJS modern, there's no `initComponent` for `Ext.Container`, besides `constructor` which function would replace `initComponent` in Modern?

I'm having an issue because I implemented the component initialization in the constructor and when I display the component again it runs the constructor again with the `config` set as the previous updated `config`, so the component renders things multiple times where it should only render once.

```js
Ext.define('AppName.view.settings.CalloutBox', {
   extend: 'Ext.Container',
   xtype: 'calloutbox',
   layout : {
      type  : 'hbox',
   },

   constructor: function(config) {
      // Added this to avoid the bug I commented above.
      if (config.cls) {
         this.callParent(arguments);

         return;
      }

      config.cls = `myclass`;

      // Here I programmatically add elements. These cause the bug
      // because on next run of this constructor these will be
      // added again.
      config.items = [{
         xtype : 'container',
         cls   : `alert__icon-box`,
         layout: {
            type  : 'vbox',
            pack  : 'center',
            align : 'middle'
         },
         items: [{
            xtype :'label',
            cls   : `alert__icon`,
            html  : `<i class="x-font-icon md-icon-alert"></i>`,
         }]
      }];

      this.callParent(arguments);
   }
});
```

---

**Update**

I found out the cause of the duplicating elements bug. It was caused by recreating the modal that the `CalloutBox` was in every time instead of just showing the one already open.

So we had this:

```js
Ext.Viewport.add({ xtype: 'mymodal' }).show();
```

And now:

```js
      const mymodal = Ext.getCmp('mymodal');

      // If component already exists in DOM, just show it.
      if (mymodal) {
         mymodal.show();

         return;
      }

      // Else we create and show it.
      Ext.Viewport.add({ xtype: 'mymodal' }).show();
```

Comment: You want to use initialize method in the modern framework. Please share a fiddle with your code, looks like you are adding items to the class instead of the instance.

Comment: Hi @hwsw I added some example code.

Comment: Modals are handled by ExtJS. You shouldn't have to handle these yourself. Try to go with a loading mask without msg and icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check out](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/modern/Ext.Container.html#method-initialize) the `initialize` template method of `Container` and other classes in Modern Toolkit. Try running the following code in a fiddle:

```
Ext.define('MyContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'mycontainer',
    initialize: function () {
        this.add({
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                pack: 'center',
                align: 'middle'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'label',
                html: 'label1',
            },{
                xtype: 'label',
                html: 'label2',
            }]});
    }
});

Ext.create({
    "xtype": "mycontainer",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```